# The difference between MOV [reg],reg .. MOV reg,reg

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to Assembly, and i would like to finally solve this (my) problem

[image]

Well here it is, it seems that EAX reg has the value 00 00 93 19 and p2 00 00 10 00 (but as i understand it is used as an address)
When MOV [p2],AX is done  .. ([] means that it looks at 0x00001000 and at this address it will change those values to 19 ..etc according to the little endian strategy)
So am i supposed to understand it like ..
EAX has its own address as (for example (only for idea) 0x00000523 and at this address has  the value 00 00 93 19
and p2 has its own adress 00 00 10 00 and the value 00 00 66 65 (before the change)

so after the change  p2 will look like: address 00 00 10 00 and has value 00 00 93 19 ?

How would it look if I wrote MOV p2, AX

Comment: Is `p2` supposed to represent the name of another register here, or is it a constant?

Comment: `p2` isn't a register. It's a symbol so it's form is  `MOV [mem], reg`. What `MOV p2, AX`means depends on the assembler you're using.

Answer (score 1):

After `mov [p2], ax` the address `00 00 10 00` content will be `00009319`

`mov p2,ax` is not valid insofar as p2 do not represent an address.

> EAX has its own address as (for example (only for idea) 0x00000523 and at this address has the value 00 00 93 19

That's wrong. `EAX` is a register and registers does not have own addresses. They just have content.

Comment: Okay I understand ... so then what is the difference between MOV EAX,EBX and MOV [EAX],EBX ?

Comment: MOV EAX,EBX put the content of ebx to eax but MOV [EAX],EBX put the content of ebx to the address that is eax has. for example eax=00123456. mov [eax], ebx put the content of ebx in 00123456 address.

Comment: Yep I know, that's why i was asking... because as you wrote .. MOV EAX, EBX put the content of ebx to eax, which means that the content of ebx will be saved at eax address   .. so eax (at some address) will have "new value" from EBX

Answer (score 0):

In some (most?) x86 assemblers, the instruction `mov p2,ax` is the same as `mov [p2],ax`. Both are moving the contents of a register into memory at the address associated with `p2`.

They are both synonyms for:

```
mov word ptr p2, ax
```

As I recall, other assemblers would reject `mov p2,ax` as an invalid instruction, but `mov [p2],ax` was legal.

Comment: In MASM/TASM syntax, a bare symbol is a memory operand.  In NASM syntax (also used by YASM), it's an immediate constant (and thus can't be a destination).  NASM is easy: `[]` always means dereference, and is always required.  In MASM, `[]` is sometimes not required.